# heuristic approaches for matching points

Tags: image-processing, matching, point, heuristics

I am using SIFT and SURF algorithm. But I need a research about heuristic approaches in point&feature matching. What are the heuristic approaches for matching points in image processing?

Answer (score 0):

The [FLANN matcher](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/features2d_common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html#flannbasedmatcher) may be a useful heuristic matcher for your problem, and fits in well with SIFT and SURF descriptors. There are also various other classifiers such as decision trees/ferns/forests and machine learning techniques, but if you're only looking for matchers and not classifiers, I would go with FLANN.